# PHP MySQLi Prepared Statement

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

I am trying to create my first prepared statement with MySQLi since i know that the way i was doing my Query was open to SQL Injections.

I really dont understand the bind_param and bind_result part of this. Can someone please explain this to me in the most dumb down way possible.

Here was my query that works.

```
$sql = "UPDATE formdata SET name = '$varName', email = '$varEmail', address = '$varAddress', city = '$varCity', state = '$varState', zip = '$varZip', submitDate  = '$varDate' WHERE promoCode = '$varPromo'";
$mysqli->query($sql);
```

And here is my attempt at a prepared statement.

```
$query = "UPDATE formdata SET name = ?, email = ?, address = ?, city = ?, state = ?, zip = ?, submitDate  = ? WHERE promoCode = '$varPromo'";
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query);
$stmt->bind_param("s", $varName, $varName, $varEmail, $varAddress, $varCity, $varState, $varZip, $varDate);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($varName, $varName, $varEmail, $varAddress, $varCity, $varState, $varZip, $varDate);
$stmt->fetch();

header("location: index.php?success=1");
exit();
```

Comment: Travis, why don't you start with some tutorial about this? I can't imagine that those two methods are not explained in different level of details and flavour of formulation. http://php.net/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some error message information would be helpful, however, there is a couple things I should point out.

For starters, in `bind_param()` the first argument indicates what information is being passed in (string, int, etc) and you must specify each piece of information **in the same order you list your arguments**.  E.g. if you have two strings and two integers you would put:

```
$stmt->bind_param("ssii", $str1, $str2, $int1, $int2);
```

Also you have a the variable `$varName` that you use twice in both your `bind_param()` and `bind_result()`.  It is best practice to use different variable names for each piece of information.  However, in this case since you are executing an `UPDATE` statement you are only going to get a count of the rows affected, so instead of `$stmt->bind_result(...);` use `echo $stmt->affected_rows;`

A select statement would be a totally different scenario, in which case you would bind result information to variables.  However, you should take a look at the tutorial hakre posted above.  They have a lot of decent examples and will help give you a starting point for writing your own prepared statements and getting results back.

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation. I guess i learn better through watching videos and have someone explain it step by step vs reading all of these tutorials. I managed to make it work from watching some youtube videos.